# Accessing s3 bucket from .net

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can successfully view files in an S3 bucket using WinSCP, by supplying the following settings:

- file protocol = Amazon S3
- host name = s3.amazonaws.com
- access key ID
- secret access key
- remote directory = my subfolder (under advanced)

However, I want to do the same using .NET Core and I'm having trouble. I've installed the AWSSDK.S3 nuget package and have the following code:

```
foreach (var region in RegionEndpoint.EnumerableAllRegions)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
        {
            BucketName = bucket,
            MaxKeys = 10
        };

        using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(accessID, secret, region))
        {
            var response = await client.ListObjectsV2Async(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.S3Objects.Count);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I don't know the region, so I tried them all and I get exceptions saying: "The specified bucket does not exist".

WinSCP works so I must have the right settings, but I don't know if I've configured the .NET library correctly. Are the credentials I've been supplied not the standard type? Am I using the wrong library/protocol in .net?

Comment: What `bucket` name are you supplying? It should simply be the name of the bucket, with no periods.

Comment: The bucket name is along the lines of Company-name-dataset and has no periods but does have the initial captial and - separators

Comment: Bucket names normally do not have uppercase characters. The one exception is buckets created some time ago in the us-east-1 region. You might want to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 ls` command to view the bucket name as it appears in API calls. You can then use `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name` to verify that it is a valid name.

Comment: Doh! A lowercase only bucket name fixed the problem. It seems the WinSCP developers were smart enough to call ToLower() on my supplied bucket before connecting. Thanks for the help John!

Comment: @Brett **TIP:** I tend to use the console once (to check out how it works, get the steps, security, validation rules, etc) then I do it via code and the API.